# Mis peticiones a BD se multiplican misteriosamente: Python y SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

**CONTEXTO.** Python 3.9.1, Flask 2.0.1, Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1, SQLAlchemy==1.4.25

**QUÉ QUIERO HACER.** Eliminar registros de la base de datos MySQL

**PROBLEMA.** Tengo una vista que lista mis blogposts en un [datatables](https://datatables.net/) (el datatable funciona con Ajax). Cada fila contiene un botón para borrar el registro. Los registros que intento borrar se eliminan ok de la BD. El problema es que cada borrado ejecuta tantas peticiones a la BD como veces he intentado borrar registros. Es decir, el 1er borrado ejecuta una petición, el 2do ejecuta 2, el 3ro ejecuta 3, etc. Después de unos 10 posts eliminados salta el error: `SQLAlchemyError: Excepción SQLAlchemyError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached`. La consola muestra esto según el ejemplo que doy al haber borrado los registros 48, 49 y 50:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2021 20:57:43] "POST /backend/blog/delete/48 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2021 20:57:47] "POST /backend/blog/delete/49 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2021 20:57:47] "POST /backend/blog/delete/49 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2021 20:57:51] "POST /backend/blog/delete/50 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2021 20:57:51] "POST /backend/blog/delete/50 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2021 20:57:51] "POST /backend/blog/delete/50 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

**QUÉ ESTOY HACIENDO.**

*Controlador* (no eliminé código aquí, tal cual lo tengo)

```
@blueprint.route('/delete/<id>', methods=['POST'])
def delete(id):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        respuesta = {
            'estatus': False,
            'toastrMsg': '...',
            'toastrType': 'danger',
            'toastrTitle': '...'
        }
        blogpostExistente = Blog.getById(id)
        blogpostTitle = '?'
        booleano = bool(blogpostExistente)

        if booleano:
            blogpostTitle = blogpostExistente.title
            Blog.delete(id)
            respuesta = {
                'estatus': True,
                'toastrMsg': 'Blogpost eliminado ('+blogpostTitle+' con ID: '+id+')',
                'toastrType': 'success',
                'toastrTitle': '¡Yeeeha!'
            }
        else:
            respuesta = {
                'estatus': False,
                'toastrMsg': 'Imposible eliminar blogpost, pues no se pudo recuperar el post (ID: '+id+') de la base de datos',
                'toastrType': 'danger',
                'toastrTitle': '¡Ooops!'
            }
        return jsonify(respuesta)
```

*Modelo*

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool_size=10, max_overflow=20)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
sessionDB = scoped_session(session_factory)

class Blog(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'blog'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    author_id = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    title = Column(String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    contenido = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime(255), default=datetime.now())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime(255), default=datetime.now(), onupdate=datetime.now())

    # Este método se encarga de recuperar los datos que van a parar al datatables
    def collect_data_serverside(self, request):
        DATA = []
        query = sessionDB.query(User, Blog).filter(User.id==Blog.author_id)
        for u, b in query.all():
            DATA.append({'A': b.id, 'B': u.nombre, 'C': b.title, 'D': b.created_at})
        columns = table_schemas.BLOG
        return ServerSideTable(request, DATA, columns, True, True, 'backend.blog', 'C', 'table_blogposts').output_result()

    def delete(id):
        sessionDB.query(Blog).filter(Blog.id == id).delete()
        sessionDB.commit()
        sessionDB.close()
        sessionDB.remove()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**CÓMO HE INTENTADO SOLUCIONAR EL PROBLEMA.**

Pensé que quizá pudiera darse una mejoría si cambiaba el modo en como borro los registros. Intenté gestionar la base de datos de forma distinta, así que declaré: `db = SQLAlchemy()` en mi **init**.py principal, arriba de `create_app()` (la estructura de mi proyecto es la misma que la del [tutorial oficial de Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/)), y luego utilicé esa instancia de SQLAlchemy en mi método `delete()`:

```
db.create_all(app=create_app())
db.session.query(Blog).filter_by(id=id).delete()
db.session.commit()
```

No funcionó. El problema persiste.

Cualquier comentario o ayuda es absolutamente bienvenido. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

He resuelto mi problema. Resumo mi solución en 2 puntos:

**Primero.** La consola sigue mostrando una petición en el primer borrado, dos en el segundo, etc. :(

**Segundo.** Sin embargo, he resuelto lo más importante, es decir, que el aplicativo no lance el error: `QueuePool limit of size <x> overflow <y> reached, connection timed out, timeout <z>`. Resulta que tengo dos modelos: user.py y blog.py. En ambos yo estaba declarando la sesión a la BD:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool_size=10, max_overflow=20)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
sessionDB = scoped_session(session_factory)
```

Asumí naturalmente que debía poner este código en cada modelo. La verdad no sé cómo se me ocurrió pero me aventuré a eliminar este código de blog.py y dejar solamente el código de user.py. ¡El resultado fue que el aplicativo seguía funcionando! Y no sólo eso, sino que pude borrar tantos posts como quise sin volver a ver el error de `QueuePool limit of size`.